# If a employers supposed to calulate drive time pay with your weekly gross pay

Tags: united-states, taxes, income

I live in Nv if that matters. I have 2 questions

1. My employer pays me $53.00 per job. A job is 1 to 4 hours so I make $12.50 a hr if broken down as a hourly pay. I also get drive time I keep a company van at my home and drive from my home to the job. He pays me $11.00 hr as long as the drive takes a hr to get to. If it takes 30 min he wont pay drive time even if I have another job after that's 30 min away from the first one. From what I have read he should be paying me. Drive time from my house where I clock in on my phone. To the first job the second job and he doesn't have to pay for the drive home. But I also pick up my helpers and drop them off. So my first question is should he be paying for all the time I spent driving since I clock in before I leave my house. Then I pick-up my helpers and drop them off before I going home for the night or is he really allowed to only pay drive time if a job is a hr or more away.
2. My second question also has to do with drive-time. Like I said before I make $53.00 per job broke down into hrly 12.50 lets say I did 6 jobs for the week at $53.00  a job I gross $318.00 before taxes say I drove to one job that was a hr away that week I get $11.00 for that 1 hr of drive time is this $11.00 supposed to be added to my weekly gross pay of $318.00 before taxes or should it be taxed separately. Do to the different rates of pay. Its making a big difference in my Fed withholdings if I tax $11.00 I don't pay fed withholdings but I do pay social security and Medicare tax on $11.00 . So should he be adding the $11 to my weekly gross then tax it or should they be taxed separately.

Comment: The issue may also be tangled up in the fact that you are paid per job. If it only takes an hour do you still get $53? Also $53 divided by 4 is $13.25 an hour.

Comment: Thanks for the math lesson I had for got my 3 dollar raise I was actually going off of when I was making 50 dollars a job . Yes for the most part I do make 53 if it only takes a hour but the issue at hand is should they be adding the 11 dollars an hr for drive time to my gross pay at the end of the week . Since my regular rate of pay is 13.25 an hr and drive time is $11 an hour should they be taxed togeather or separate since they are different rates of pay .

Answer (score 2):

Reimbursements for business expenses are generally not taxable, but the commute from home to the job and back is not considered business travel and if they're paying for that it *is* taxable income. I don't think carpooling changes that, but I am not a tax lawyer or accountant.

The rest of your questions seem to be company policy issues. There is no "should" here. You aren't required to pick up the other guys, but he isn't required to reimburse those miles (or employ you) so think carefully about your priorities before pushing back. Never invoke what thou canst not banish.

Comment: How about adding my drive time to my weekly gross then taxing the drive time hrs with my weekly pay hour when they are both different rates of pay

Comment: And yes I am required to pick the other guys up.

Comment: Take that up with the company; that's up to company and employees to decide, witbin the limits of the tax code. They can pay you what they want to pay you; they may have no choice about whether or how it is taxed.

Comment: And yes I am required to pick the other guys up. I dont drive my personal car to the job its not car pooling its a company van.as soon as I get in the van I clock in . Using a app my company uses to do invoicing i start drive time and and end drive time to each job.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting paid by the job, not by the hour, so I don't see why you think the employer is obligated to pay you for the drive time.  The only way that might be true, as far as I can see, is if he were avoiding paying you minimum wage by structuring your employment this way.  It looks like to me you're over the minimum wage based on what you wrote.  At maximum "unpaid" drive time (59 min each way) and maximum length of job (4 hours as you stated it), gives your minimum hourly rate of $8.83/hr. The federal minimum wage is currently $7.25/hr, so you're over that.  A quick search online suggests that NV does have a higher minimum at $8.25/hr under some conditions, but you're still over that too.

The fact that you're required to pick-up the helpers and that you have a company car at home probably does mean that you're "on the clock" from the moment that you leave your house, but, again, you're not actually being paid by the clock.  As long as no other law is being broken (and it appears from your telling that there isn't), then the employer can set any policy for how to compute the compensation that he wants.

Regarding taxes, the employer probably has no discretion there.  You're making what you're making, and the employer needs to tax it in total.  Since you're driving a company vehicle from home, I don't think that you're entitled to any reimbursement (vs. wages) that would not be taxed unless maybe you pay for gas yourself.  The gas money, if applicable, should be reimbursable as a business expense and that generally would not be taxed.